# Error while trying to connect to MySQL server. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to connect my Node server to MySQL server running on localhost:3306. But I keep getting this error message.

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server running on port 3000
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at PromisePool.execute (/mnt/d/learn_NodeJS/nodejs_intro/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:374:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/learn_NodeJS/nodejs_intro/server.js:27:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: -111,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined,
  sqlMessage: undefined
}
```

I tried to google and research around to find out possible solutions to this and found [article](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1-3306)

Which basically says that root account is no longer permitted to connect to MySQL due to a rule change that was enforced a few years ago.

So I followed the instructions and created a new user through the MySQL Command Line Client.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'xaliz'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'xaliz0605';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
 
mysql> GRANT ALL ON `database`.* TO 'xaliz'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

I checked in 'Users and Priviledges' section I do see the user I created now and checked all the priviledges. And I've confirmed that the server is indeed running.

This is my 'database.js' file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
 
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'xaliz',
  database: 'node-complete',
  password: 'xaliz0605',
  port: 3306,
});
 
module.exports = pool.promise();
```

I've checked that the password is correct.

This is the 'server.js' file:

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');
const errorController = require('./controllers/error');
 
const db = require('./utils/database');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');
 
db.execute('SELECT * FROM products')
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);
 
// 404 Error Catch-All Middleware
app.use(errorController.get404);
 
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I have created a dummy table on the local instance with a few rows added.

I am using MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE and using WSL:Ubuntu 20.04. The version of 'mysql2' is '3.8.0' when I installed this. I can't understand the issue here so it'd be of immense help if someone can help me fix this.

Comment: Connection refused means that the mysql client cannot even connect to mysql. It has nothing to do with access rights. Either mysql is not running at all, or listens on another port or something is blocking your network connection / socket file.

Comment: You have conflicting port number usage.  You say you are trying to connect on 3306.  The display from your first information indicates the server is 'running on port 3000'.